# Equivalence relations - Cardinality of a subset

Tags: modular-arithmetic, modules, equivalence-relations

Let $R$ be a subset of Z $*$ Z, the relation being congruent mod 4.

How many equivalence relations $E$ are such that $R$ is a subset of $E$ and $E$ is a subset of Z $*$ Z.

I know that (mod 4) has 4 equivalence classes. But I am stuck with this fact. Does this mean that $R$ is composed of these 4 equivalence classes? Wouldn't that mean that $E$ has an infinite amount of equivalence relations, composed by all the equivalence classes greater than 3?

I am just starting to see the concept of relations. So, it would be a lot of help if you could give me any tips on solving this problem!

Comment: We just call them "relations," not "relationships."

Comment: It may help you to picture what is going on here by recognizing that equivalence relations are directly correlated with partitions and vice versa.  The equivalence relation over $\Bbb Z$ where $a\simeq b\iff a\equiv b\pmod{4}$ corresponds to the partition $\{\dots,-8,-4,0,4,8,\dots\}, \{\dots, -3,1,5,\dots\},\{\dots,-2,2,6,\dots\},\{\dots,-1,3,7,\dots\}$.  Now... think about what it means for $E$ to be a superset of $R$.  Since $E$ is a superset of $R$, does that mean that $1$ needs to be related to $5$?  To $9$?

Comment: Compare your problem now to the question of how many partitions there are of the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$.  Try to see and understand why this is the same question you are asked.